# Debugging Android ValueAnimator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I have been trying to create a collapse/expand animation for my `CardView` using Kotlin extension functions and `ValueAnimator`. Here is the code for my animations (the `CardView` extension functions):

```
fun CardView.collapse() {
    val content = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_content)
    val arrow = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.contents_arrow)
    val currentHeight = content.layoutParams.height

    val rvAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentHeight, 0).apply {
        addUpdateListener{ updatedAnimation ->
            val params = content.layoutParams
            params.height = updatedAnimation.animatedValue as Int
            content.layoutParams = params
        }
        duration = 1000
    }

    val arrowAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(00f, 180f).apply {
        addUpdateListener { updatedAnimation ->
            arrow.rotation = updatedAnimation.animatedValue as Float
        }

        duration = 1000
        startDelay = 250
    }

    AnimatorSet().apply {
        playTogether(rvAnimator, arrowAnimator)
        start()
    }

}

fun CardView.expand(maxHeight: Int) {
    val content = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_content)
    val arrow = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.contents_arrow)

    val rvAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, maxHeight).apply {
        addUpdateListener{updatedAnimation ->
            val params = content.layoutParams
            params.height = updatedAnimation.animatedValue as Int
            content.layoutParams = params
        }
        duration = 1000
    }

    val arrowAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(180f, 0f).apply {
        addUpdateListener { updatedAnimation ->
            arrow.rotation = updatedAnimation.animatedValue as Float
        }

        duration = 1000
        startDelay = 250
    }

    AnimatorSet().apply {
        playTogether(rvAnimator, arrowAnimator)
        start()
    }

}

fun CardView.isCollapsed(): Boolean {
    val content = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_content)
    return content.layoutParams.height == 0

}
```

And the on-click which initiates the animation:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SectionViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        if ((it as CardView).isCollapsed()) {
            it.expand(holder.maxHeight)
        } else {
            it.collapse()
        }
    }
}
```

However, my animation seems to cause some very strange drawing issues. There's some sort of delay when the `CardView` is clicked the first time. More concerning though is the fact that the `CardView` always goes back to being expanded once the animation is over:

[image]

When the arrow is pointing up, the `CardView` should be collapsed and vice versa when the arrow is pointing down.

Would anyone be able to provide any input on how to solve this issue? I don't even know where to begin when debugging an animation. Any input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the collapse animation.

You can simply reverse the animations which you have created to expand, like this:

```
rvAnimator.reverse()
arrowAnimator.reverse()
```

for this, you can't use the AnimatorSet, you have to start both the animations by yourself like this:

```
rvAnimator.start()
arrowAnimator.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, splitting out each animator and calling `start()` on each one doesn't appear to have resolved the issue for me :/